# Does d/d(spinor) anticommute with a spinor?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, differentiation, spinors, grassmann-numbers

Weyl spinors anticommute (see, e.g. [Why isn't the anticommutativity of spinors sufficient as "spin-statistics-theorem"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333955/37286)).

If we consider the derivative, with respect to a Weyl spinor $\frac{d}{d\chi}$, does this derivative anticommute with a given  Weyl spinor $\chi$?

To be explicit, consider the product

$$ \frac{d}{d\chi} \chi f(x) \underbrace{=}_{\text{product rule}} \left(\frac{d}{d\chi} \chi  \right ) f(x) \pm  \chi  \left(\frac{d}{d\chi}  f(x)   \right )  ,$$
where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary object, such that $\frac{d}{d\chi}  f(x)  \neq 0$. **Which sign here is correct? Does the product rule for spinors involve a minus sign instead of a plus sign?**

Comment: possible duplicate: [Derivative with respect to a spinor of the free Dirac lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301860).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are two different definitions of $d\over d\psi$ for spinor $\psi$, whether acting from right or left. It satisfies the calculus of Grasmann algebra(anticommuting numbers). If you take the definition of $d\over d\psi$ to act from left, then if $f(x)$ is commutative number(c-number in literature usually), then it should be 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\chi} \chi f(x) \underbrace{=}_{\text{product rule}} \left(\frac{d}{d\chi} \chi  \right ) f(x) +  \chi  \left(\frac{d}{d\chi}  f(x)   \right )  
\end{equation}
or if $f(x)$ contains odd number of spinors, then it's a Grassmann number, the sign should be minus.

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly, be aware that a spinor might not be Grassmann-odd for various reasons, e.g. if it is a [ghost field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_(physics)).
2. Secondly, a Grassmann-odd derivative $\frac{\partial^L}{\partial \chi}$ does not always anticommute with a Grassmann-odd variable $\tilde{\chi}$, cf. the title question (v1). E.g. if $\tilde{\chi}$ depends on $\chi$.
3. More generally, the graded [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) for a derivative acting from left ($L$) reads
   $$\frac{\partial^L(fg)}{\partial \chi}~=~\frac{\partial^Lf}{\partial \chi}g+(-1)^{|\chi||f|}f\frac{\partial^Lg}{\partial \chi}, $$
   while for a derivative acting from right ($R$) it is
   $$\frac{\partial^R(fg)}{\partial \chi}~=~f\frac{\partial^Rg}{\partial \chi}+(-1)^{|\chi||g|}\frac{\partial^Rf}{\partial \chi}g. $$
   Here $|f|$ denotes the Grassmann parity of $f$, and $\chi$ is any type of variable (not necessarily a spinor). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301860/2451) related Phys.SE post.
4. For completeness, let us mention that the left & right derivatives are equal up to a sign factor:
   $$\frac{\partial^Lf}{\partial\chi}~=~(-1)^{(|f|+1)|\chi|}\frac{\partial^Rf}{\partial\chi}.$$