# How are Grassmann fields "forced upon us" by representation theory of $SO(d-1,1)$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, fermions, spin-statistics, anticommutator

I would like to know if anticommuting fields (which physicists use as fermions) emerge naturally from the spin representation theory of $SO(d-1,1)$. Is the fact that spinor fields anticommute a physics result or a math result?

We can build *non-spin* representations of $SO(d-1,1)$ out of the fundamental vector representation. The vector space $V$ on which this representation acts is just Mink$_d$. We can define scalar, vector, tensor, etc. fields on $V$ as usual,
$$\phi(x),A_{\nu}(x), T_{\mu\nu}(x), \text{etc}.\qquad x\in V.$$

These fields **commute** $\phi(x) A_{\nu}(x) = A_{\nu}(x) \phi(x)$.

We built *spin* representations of $SO(d-1,1)$ (following Harris & Fulton) by first constructing the Clifford algebra

$$C(d-1,1) = T^*(V)/ I(d-1,1)$$
where $$T^*(V)=\bigoplus_{n \geq 0}V^{\otimes n} $$
and $I(d-1,1)$ is the ideal generated by elements of the form $\{v^{\mu},w^{\nu}\} - 2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ where $v,w \in V$. For instance if $\eta^{\mu\nu} = 0$ then $C(d-1,1)$ is just the exterior algebra; but we take $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ to have signature $(d-1,1)$. Then we can define the usual Dirac gamma matrices $\Gamma^{\mu}$ and $[\Gamma^{\mu},\Gamma^{\nu}]$ furnishes a representation of $SO(d-1,1)$.

Now, as for non-spin, I presume we can define spinor fields $\eta(c)$ where $c$ belongs to the $2^{d/2}$ dimensional space $C(d-1,1)$. Is there some consistency condition which implies that two such fields satisfy

$$\eta(c) \chi(c') = -\chi(c') \eta(c)$$

directly from the definition of $C(d-1,1)$ perhaps? Why must $\eta,\chi$ be **anticommuting** in stark contrast with $\phi, A_{\nu}, T_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: possible dup.? [What is the spin-statistics theorem in higher dimensions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/455539/84967).

Comment: $\eta,\chi$ need not be anticommuting. Consider e.g. the case where Spin(d) is a color (gauge) group (in the same spirit as SU(N) for QCD) rather than a spacetime symmetry. Bosons in the spinor rep. of the gauge group commute.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Discussion of this question in Peskin, An Introduction to QFT, section 3.5.